# EventHandlers, ActionListeners, and buttons. How to register a Handler on three buttons?

Tags: java, button, actionlistener, inner-classes, eventhandler

I don't think the rest of the code is needed but if I'm missing something let me know. I don't know what it wants me to do but the instructions provided to me by my professor isn't very clear to me.

Anyway, here is what I have so far:

```
    // ***** Task 5: Student code restarts here
  // Note: search for and complete Task 4 before performing this task
  // declare and instantiate an EventHandler

  // register the handler on the 3 buttons
  // that you declared in Task 1
  
   button1.addEventHandler(EventHandler event);
  
   // task 5 ends here
 

 // ***** Task 4: Student code restarts here
 // create a private inner class that implements EventHandler
 // your method should identify which of the 3 buttons
 //    was the source of the event
 // depending on which button was pressed,
 //    call the setUpGame method of the GameView class
 //    with arguments 3, 4, or 5
 // the API of that method is:
 //   public void setUpGame( int nSides )
 private class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
 {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent event)
   {
     if (event.getSource() == button1)
     {
        gameView.setUpGame(3);
     }
     else if (event.getSource() == button2)
     {
       gameView.setUpGame(4);
     }
     else if (event.getSource() == button3)
     {
       gameView.setUpGame(5);
     }
   }
 }
 // task 4 ends here
```

In task 5 it says to declare and instantiate an EventHandler but I'm confused by this because aren't we using one in task 4? Also, almost all of the research I have done people aren't using EventHandlers for buttons they are using ActionListeners. I don't know what the difference is and I don't know how to implement either of them.

If you need me to I can provide screenshots or something! I'm new to this site so forgive me if this is messy.

Comment: Where was the `setupGame` method defined? in the enclosing class?

Comment: @gaborsch Hey there! The setUpGame method was defined in another class all together called GameView. In GameView, the setUpGame method is public and void. Hope this helps!

Comment: You need an instance of the `GameView` class - maybe you are supposed to create the inner class within the `GameView` class. If you do this way, the method call will work as expected. You can try the `GameView.this.setUpGame(n)` syntax, too (works in the described case only)

Comment: The instructions don't want me to touch any of the other classes so I don't think changing stuff in the GameView class will work in my case. I tried doing GameView.this.setUpGame(n); but it says this "not an enclosing class:GameView" If you want I can post the whole code?

Comment: Check the GameView class then. How is it instantiated? Is it singleton? Where is it instantiated from? Where (and how) are the instance(s) accessible from? Probably there is some way which is good for your inner class.

Comment: The GameView class is public and it extends GridPane. Here is the code for the setUpGame method:                                                                                              public void setUpGame( int newSide )
 {
  game.setUpGame( newSide );
  setUpGameGUI( );
 }

Comment: Welp, I think I figured it out and I'm very angry at myself and just everything. I don't even think I want to try and explain it because I don't even really understand it...

Comment: Welcome to the club! You made the first step to become a dwveloper...

Comment: Well I thought I got it but now it doesn't seem to even run the setUpGame method correctly and on top of that the last task I have to do is super confusing. I'm gonna add to the post so you can see what I mean. Also, I really appreciate the help! I've been working on the same stupid method for a week now and I'm kinda going insane.